# A generic way to display percentages in v-text-field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a form, which has a field that displays a decimal as a percentage:

```
<v-text-field
   label="Investment Fee"
   suffix="%"
   v-model="percentageFee"
/>
```

The v-model is linked to a computed property with a getter and setter:

```
computed: {
    percentageFee: {
      get: function(){
        return +(this.investment.investment_fee * 100).toFixed(2)
      },
      set: function(newValue){
        this.investment.investment_fee = (newValue/100).toFixed(4);
      }
    }
  },
```

This all works fine. It displays a decimal from an API call as a percentage, and converts an input percentage back to a decimal before PATCH.

My problem is, it seems ridiculous to create a computed property for every field I want to display as a percentage. There are a lot and it would be extremely repetitive.

I've solved this problem for formatting currency using `VCurrencyField`, which is wonderful, but no such component exists for percentages (or other generic formatting for that matter).

Please help.

Comment: You have to create your own component wrapping this. The component gets the prop "value" (it comes from v-model) and emits the "input" event (it goes to v-model).

Comment: 4 years later and I've learned a lot :) You are correct - now I just use some generic mixins to achieve this result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is, as it seems to me, that the computed property is not generic, I would just create a function in the method hook and use that instead, passing in the prop each time you call it, and optionally with a `toPlace` parameter to set the decimal places.

```
methods: {
    percentageFee (decimalVal, toPlaces) {
        let decPlaces = toPlaces || 2; //or whatever default you want
        let percentage = (decimalVal * 100).toFixed(decPlaces);
        return percentage;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's easy enough to convert the data to a percentage, we can do that with a method or Vue filter. The thing I am having difficulty with is keeping Vue's v-model functionality and manipulate the input data back to a decimal once it has been entered.

Comment: This does not answer the question.